# python fbprophet error, TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, module, pypi

On using the Python library 'fbprophet' it throw the error, TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```py
import fbprophet as Prophet
m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality= True)
```

on executing it throws this error,

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-53e30b441246>", line 1, in <module>
    m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality= True)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Any help on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved using

```py
m = Prophet.Prophet(weekly_seasonality= True)
```

Comment: Amazing that the Quick Start guide leads you right into that issue from the very start.